# Debug PySpark in VS Code

Tags: apache-spark, visual-studio-code, pyspark

I'm building a project in PySpark using VS Code. I have Python and Spark installed and PySpark is correctly imported and running in a Jupyter notebook. Do do so, I run:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext('local')
spark = SparkSession(sc)

[my code... ]
```

Now, how do I debug my PySpark code in VS Code? I don't want to run `findspark` in my project. Do I need to create a virtual environment and run a pre-script? What are the best practices?

Answer (score -2):

So the steps I followed and what I learnt:

- make sure Python, Spark and the environmental variables are correctly installed and set
- Create a virtual environment, and pip install all required libraries (including pyspark)
- Run de debugger. The debugger will just analyze the code and not run it. So a `SparkContext` and a `SparkSession` are not required.